# When does android's ListActivity class call setContentView()?

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I'm trying to use the `requestWindowFeature()` function to set a custom title view on a list activity. The method works fine with a view that only subclasses `Activity`, but whenever I try the same method with a `ListActivity` subclass, it errors, giving me a NullPointerException when I try to programmatically modify the title view.

I believe the problem pertains to the fact that `requestWindowFeature()` needs to be called before `setContentView()`. Because `ListActivity` takes care of setting the content view for you, I don't know when that is being called. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setContentView is called whenever you interact with the List, for example calling getList() or setAdapter() on listactivity. See the [source](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/app/ListActivity.java#ListActivity) of listactivity

Comment: Any ideas why my code is giving me a nullpointerexception? Here's a gist of the relevant code. https://gist.github.com/1118871 I did a quick check and requestWindowFeature is returning true, so my view should be loaded, shouldn't it?

Comment: ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title)) == null ?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`ListActivity` doesn't take care of calling `setContentView` for you: you still need to do it yourself. Your content view has to have an appropriately-named `ListView` but you still need to call `setContentView` yourself. Just call `requestWindowFeature` right after the `super.onCreate` call in `onCreate` and then call `setContentView` after that and you should be golden.</strike>

EDIT: my mistake, you are quite right (I didn't know that: I've always just called `setContentView` with a custom layout).

It appears from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java;hb=HEAD) that there is no way to slip a `requestWindowFeature` call before the `setContentView` call in `ListActivity`: it ALWAYS calls `setContentView` immediately after the `super.onCreate` call. You can try calling `requestWindowFeature` before you call `super.onCreate` but I suspect that won't work any better.

I don't think you will be able to use the default `ListActivity` for this: you'll probably need to use a regular Activity and manually do the ListView bindings.

Comment: this is incorrect. ListActivity provides a default view for you, but you can override it with your own if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem, for any googlers, was to copy the source of the `ListActivity` class, and also the layout_content.xml file into my own app's package, and subclass from this instead of Android's `ListActivity` class. I then added an `onCreate()` method to this class where I set request the window feature(s) and *then* call the `setContentView()` method. Hack? Probably. Works? Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, `requestWindowFeature()` gives a NullPointerException if it's called after the `super.onCreate(bundle);` call. Another reason is if you have called `setContentView` first as well.

`super.onCreate(bundle);` and `setContentView` must be called after all `requestWindowFeature()` calls are made.