# Exception on hiding title of the application using ListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titlebar

I have a class extending `ListActivity` and I am trying to hide the default TitleBar (I think it's called ActionBar) using the code below. It works on a regular activity, but not on the `ListActivity`. How do I accomplish the same in this scenario?

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(b);
        // Tried Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE here as well
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myclass);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The result is a NullPointerException. The full error stack trace is here if you need it: http://pastebin.com/VLR5dE8m

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace here? I'm behind a corporate proxy.. :|

Comment: try **Window.FEATURE** after **setContentView()**. Just a thought.

Comment: call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) after super.onCreate() and setContentView()..... set the window first then set No title bar option.

Comment: OR you can also Write this "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in manifest under activity tag

Comment: what's line 50 ? getActionBar seems null to me

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does android's ListActivity class call setContentView()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903487/when-does-androids-listactivity-class-call-setcontentview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the actionbar: getActionBar().hide(). Also see this answer: [How to disable action bar permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456835/how-to-disable-action-bar-permanently)

Answer (score 1):

to disable Titltbar,, use this code in your manifest file ,it will help you.

<
activity
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>

Answer (score 0):

I think You should not use requestWindowFeature() if you are using ActionBar. You can hide title of ActionBar with this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)

Comment: that's useless since it will just show an icon but without the text title next to it. what you *also* want is `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the NullPointerException is generated by `getActionBar()`. Removing the following line from the code fixed the issue.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**The final (working) code:**

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myclass);
     }
}
```

Note that `requestWindowFeature` must be called before calling the `super` class and `setContentView`.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to elaborate on your action? The code works fine and is a solution to the answer.